# How to execute autorun.inf Manually

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, autorun

I have an ISO file (I'm using Widows 10) that I mount as a drive, and it has an autorun.inf file.
How can I make windows run the script in it, so I don't have to open it in Notepad, see what it is doing, and do it manually step by step myself?

`start autorun.inf` in cmd doesn't work, it just opens it in notepad. *Open* context menu option also opens it in Notepad. Chat GPT didn't have a working solution either...

Comment: You do understand how dangerous autorun is in the modern era? What is the contents of the .inf file?  I assume NoDriveTypeAutoRun is set to 0x91?

Comment: Look at the `open=xyz` line.  If you choose to do so, paste the data after the `=` sign into your run dialog.  There is a VERY GOOD REASON this is no longer allowed.  Things like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal#External_links) are why.

Comment: autorun.inf is a text file that provides input to the shell on the how and what of autorunning that media, but the actual execution is a feature of the shell itself. as such (all else aside) the easiest way to invoke autorun on media (when there isn't a context menu entry for "Autoplay")is to unmount/mount it (to eject and reinsert it).